# error: package org.apache.commons.beanutils does not exist

Tags: java, tomcat7, web-development-server

I'm working through the example code of chapter 4 of Core Servlets and JavaServer Pages (http://volume1.coreservlets.com/archive/Chapter4.html) and I get the above error when I try to compile the BeanUtilities.java file. I thought initially it was my classpath but that seems to include the required .jar files (looking at the starttomcat prompt). I think I have the .jar files in the correct directory ($CATALINA_HOME/lib/ I'm running tomcat 7 on fedora). Any advice? Thanks & I hope your day is going better than mine, sigh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bean utils doesn't contains in the default package of JDK or Tomcat, So you need to add it manually as it is a dependency.

If you are building and web project using J2EE

Then add **[bean utils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/)** (.jar file) in your `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` directory.

**Also add all dependency in this directory**

If it's a maven project add the commons-beanutils dependency

> ```
>   <dependency>            
>       <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
>       <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
>       <version>1.9.2</version>        
>   </dependency>
> ```

Comment: Thanks Saif, I've already added those files there (no joy) - what dependencies?

Comment: nothing big its just a relationship as you are using `bean utils` library in your project so it is dependent on that library.. so its  a dependency library of your project

Comment: Thanks Saif - I struggled with this for a while, maybe there was a typo, a space or some such, in my $CLASSPATH entry for this jar.